# What are the minimum requirement of hadoop cluster for testing

Tags: distributed-computing, hadoop2

I am new to Hadoop. I am trying to built hadoop cluster to test performance of hadoop.I want to know what are the minimum cluster size,memory,disks space,number of cores,for each node(master and slave) and I want to know what would be the size of testing file. I am trying to process text file

Comment: It depends on what type of data you will be using and operations.

Comment: I am trying to process text file

Comment: You could run Hadoop on a VM with one core and about 1Gb of RAM.

Comment: I want to know what are the minimum cluster size(number of nodes)

Comment: it can be one node and if you have more than one node then it'll be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For HortonWorks

- Runs on 32-bit and 64-bit OS (Windows 7, Windows 8 and Mac OSX and LINUX)
- Your machine should have a minimum of 10 GB to able to run the VM which allocates 8GB
- <s>Virtualization enabled on BIOS</s> Only If you're running it on a VM
- Browser: Chrome 25+, IE 9+, Safari 6+, Firefox 18+ recommended. (Sandbox will not run on IE 10)

Just go to their download page http://hortonworks.com/hdp/downloads/

---

Look at Cloudera requirements you'll get this

- RAM - 4 GB
- IPv6 must be disabled.
- No blocking by iptables or firewalls; port 7180 must be open because it is used to access Cloudera Manager after installation. Cloudera Manager communicates using specific ports, which must be open.
- ext3: This is the most tested underlying filesystem for HDFS.
- CPU - the more the better
- JDK 1.7 at least

For more information you can check the following link

http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cm_ig_cm_requirements.html#cmig_topic_4_1_unique_1

Comment: I used Hortonworks, provides open source platform based on Apache Hadoop for analysing, storing and managing big data.